# How to return Completable from void methods

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I've got the following piece of code and it works perfectly when my inner data structure of the writerObj is CopyOnWriteArrayList (concurrent one) and it crashes when I use ArrayList.

Here're my questions:

- But there's only one thread in RxJava by default, isn't it?
- Will the lines (between player { ... }) execute in sync way?

My code looks as follows:

```
.flatMapCompletable { player -> {
    writerObj.write(player); // void write(Player player) adds player to inner data structure using ds.add()
    return Completable.complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the rest of your chain is coded.

Have a look at the following:

```
List<String> writerObj = new ArrayList<>();

Observable.range(0, 1000)
        .map(i -> Observable.just("hello world"))
        .flatMap(obs -> obs
                .flatMapCompletable(elem -> {
                        writerObj.add(elem);
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " executing");
                        return Completable.complete();
                })
                .toObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )
        .blockingSubscribe();
//Size of the list is not always 1000
System.out.println("The size of the list is : " + writerObj.size());
```

If you execute the code above, you might notice that the size of the List at the end is not always 1000. If you change the Implementation of List to CopyOnWriteArrayList, we get the desired result.

If you want the code in the flatMap to execute sequentially and by one thread at a time, change the flatMap to concatMap.

```
List<String> writerObj = new ArrayList<>();

Observable.range(0, 1000)
    .map(i -> Observable.just("hello world"))
    .concatMap(obs -> obs
            .flatMapCompletable(elem -> {
                    writerObj.add(elem);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " executing");
                    return Completable.complete();
            })
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    )
    .blockingSubscribe();
// Size is always 1000
System.out.println("The size of the list is : " + writerObj.size());
```

Hope it helps!